When I host it on vercel it does not render, Application Error: Client side exception occurred
main-733d4166479b8229.js:1 A client-side exception has occurred, see here for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/client-side-exception-occurred
Z   @   main-733d4166479b8229.js:1
fn  @   main-733d4166479b8229.js:1
componentDidCatch   @   main-733d4166479b8229.js:1
a.componentDidCatch.t.callback  @   framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9
lW  @   framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9
uX  @   framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9
e   @   framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9
(anonymous) @   framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9
oU  @   framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9
oP  @   framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9
r8  @   framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9
oV  @   framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9
o   @   framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9
x   @   framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:33
T   @   framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:33
Show 1 more frame[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/8MGDKomT.png)
framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'content')
    at r (main-733d4166479b8229.js:1:6282)
    at main-733d4166479b8229.js:1:6148
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.updateHead (main-733d4166479b8229.js:1:6136)
    at Object.i [as _pendingUpdate] (main-733d4166479b8229.js:1:96261)
    at main-733d4166479b8229.js:1:96533
    at uU (framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9:84106)
    at oV (framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9:113152)[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/gwzVgK9I.png)
    at o (framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:9:107705)
    at x (framework-5429a50ba5373c56.js:33:1364)

This is the error that the shows up in the console.log
I tried deleting the .next folder and reinstalled it while executing the production build.
Reinstalled node_modules, deleted previous deployments.
The issue still persists. :/

Before deploying to vercel, did you try running npm run build locally?

Yes, I did. Worked flawlessly.
